# Стилистические приёмы

Tags: метафора

Стилистические приёмы
Издатели-пираты — это метафора?
На мой вопрос отвечала панама- в каком значении тут может быть панама? Республика? Шляпа? И к какому тогда приему относится?
Сделал перевод вовремя- какой приём?
И тот же вопрос к фразе "ни звука русского"
Всем заранее спасибо за ответы)))

Answer (score 3):

Издатели-пираты — это метафора, так как подразумевается скрытое сравнение (издатели сравниваются с пиратами).
На мой вопрос отвечала панама - это метонимия (так как подразумевается женщина в панаме).
Сделал перевод вовремя - мне кажется, что это синтаксически неделимое словосочетание можно охарактеризовать как фразеологическое единство или фразеологизм.
Ни звука русского  - это эллипсис (подразумевается, что звуков не слышно).

Comment: Огромное спасибо